# Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package react

Tags: reactjs

I am getting following error in my react application. This issue started when I renamed some components and deleted some. However I look closely and imports and component names are correct. I did a fresh checkout, renamed one component and got the same issue.

```
ERROR in ./src/components/courses/CourseList.js 7:0-40
Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package ....../view/node_modules/@types/react (see exports field in ....../view/node_modules/@types/react/package.json)

ERROR in ./src/components/topics/TopicListDetail.js 7:0-51
Module not found: Error: Package path . is not exported from package ...../view/node_modules/@types/react (see exports field in ...../view/node_modules/@types/react/package.json)
```

both components are only imported in one place

```
import TopicList from "../../components/topics/TopicList";
import CourseList from "../../components/courses/CourseList";
```

Both follow the same conventions

```
function TopicList() {

    let topicList = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < topicList.length; i++)  {

        topicList.push(
            <NavLink to={"/topic/" + i} className="" key={"popular-topic-" + i}>
                <div className="">
                    <img src={"http://placeimg.com/100/100/people?" + i}
                         className="rounded-full hover:bg-sky-700" alt={"topic" + i} />
                </div>
            </NavLink>
        );

    }

    return (

        <div className="">
            pretty tailwind css
        </div>

    )
}
export default TopicList;
```

I deleted my `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and ran `npm i`. I am not seeing any errors in the js. I am not sure where to look at this point.

Here are where they are imported

```
import TopicList from "../../components/topics/TopicList";
import CourseList from "../../components/courses/CourseList";



function Home() {

        return (
            <Fragment>
                <div className="box-border hover:box-content max-width: 640px; ">
                    <TopicList/>
                    <CourseList/>
                </div>
            </Fragment>
        )

}
export default Home;
```

---

```
{
  "name": "view",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.5",
    "@react-buddy/ide-toolbox": "^2.1.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.10",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-minimal-side-navigation": "^1.9.2",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.2",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
}
```

advice?

Comment: did you try to => npm install --save @types/react

Comment: @Amryasser I just did not no effect. Thanks for posting

Comment: `import TopicList from "components/topics/TopicList";` Can you try like this? Also what is the webpack configuration

Comment: Can you check if your package.json file contains an "exports" section? If so, this section might contain some references to file locations that don't exist anymore after you deleted and renamed some modules.

Comment: @SteffenFrank I do not have an export section and I added the file to the post. Thanks for posting

Comment: I fixed the issue. In the end it was image imports in those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me ended up being image imports in the js file.

I had these mock valus:

```
import Course1 from "../../ui/course-1.png";

const [popularCourse] = useState([
    {
        ID: 1,
        title: "Learning How to Create Beautiful Scenes in Illustrator in 60 minutes",
        tutor: {
            ID: 1,
            name: "Lana Marandina",
            username: "lanamara",
            dp: "http://placeimg.com/100/100/people?tutor-" + 1,
        },
        duration: "82 min",
        poster: Course1
    },
```

Then add them to a list

```
var courseList = [];
for(let i = 0; i < popularCourse.length; i++){
    courseList.push(
        <NavLink to={"/course/" + popularCourse[i].ID} className="" key={"popular-course-" + i}>
            <div className="rounded-lg p-2" style={{
                background: "#e2e2e2 url(" + popularCourse[i].poster +") no-repeat center"
            }}>

                <div className="h-56">
                    <div className="">
                        <img src={popularCourse[i].tutor.dp} className="rounded-full"  alt="popular-course"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The array path for poster was wrong, but the IDE gave me a very unhelpful error.